# Newbie: Maven execution exception

Tags: java, maven

My java file:

```
    package hello;
    public class helloworld {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
      System.out.println("Hello World");
      }
    }
```

My pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>gs-maven</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.1.0</version>

 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.3.2</version>
         <configuration>
            <mainClass>src.main.java.hello.helloworld.Main</mainClass>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
 </project>
```

My directory structure is

```
 helloworld
    pom.xml
    src
      main
        java
          hello
            helloworld.java
```

I compiled it using

```
    mvn -e compile
```

My run command is

```
     mvn -e exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="src.main.java.hello.helloworld.Main"
```

I am getting the following error

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven- 
    plugin:1.3.2:java (default-cli) on project gs-maven: An exception 
    occured while executing the Java class. src.main.java.hello.helloworld.Main -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to 
    execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java 
    (default-cli) on  project gs-maven: An exception occured while 
    executing the Java class.  src.main.java.hello.helloworld.Main
```

I don't understand what is it mean? How to run my java program and see the output "hello world".

Comment: One general comment is that the standard convention for naming Java classes is to use UPPERCASE and CamelCase.  So you should name your class `HelloWorld` instead of `helloworld`

Comment: Can you check to see if you are generating a HelloWorld.class file after you do a ` mvn -e compile` ?

Comment: Yes it is generated in `target/classes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change :

```
<mainClass>src.main.java.hello.helloworld.Main</mainClass>
```

To :

```
<mainClass>hello.helloworld</mainClass>
```

Run it using :

```
mvn -e exec:java
```

or

```
mvn -e exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="hello.helloworld"
```

You need to understand that when you add a package statement to a class, the fully qualified name of the class should be package.classname. In your case, the package statement is `package hello;` and your class is `helloworld` so the fully qualified name of your class is `hello.helloworld` and not `src.main.java.hello.helloworld.Main`. That's where you went wrong. Note that before you move to maven, it would be a good idea to get hands on with th java and javac commands with the -cp option.

Comment: Changed in pom.xml and re compiled it and run it as ` mvn -e exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="hello.helloworld"`. But same error again. Which should be my working directory to execute it

Comment: Where do you compile it from and where do you run it from?

Comment: The directory where pom presents. Will you please explain why this change works?

Answer (score 0):

nitpick : Change your class name to HelloWorld instead of helloworld, 
and you entry of main class to hello.HelloWorld

From [java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of
>   each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple
>   and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations
>   (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form,
>   such as URL or HTML)., example class Raster; class ImageSprite;